# how to pick elements in groups of two and apply common border?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to group elements by two and apply border like [image]

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            16
            16
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
           16
           16
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            17
            17
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            17
            17
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
           18
           18
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
           18
           18
        </div>
  </div>
```

the elements are generated dynamically. how to group two by two and apply common border for that?

Comment: Does the last pair really have a lesser padding?

Comment: No, actually the paddings are even

Comment: It's just that the last pair is fitter than the rest

Comment: Do you have an example of your markup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that, using `:nth-child`

```css
.row {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.col-md-2 {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.col-md-2:nth-child(2n+1) {
  border-left: 1px solid green;
}

.col-md-2:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid green;
}

.col-md-2:nth-child(3),
.col-md-2:nth-child(4){
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            16
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
           16
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            17
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            17
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
           18
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
           18
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to assign classes to similar elements like:

```
<div class='red'></div>
```

Then in the head tag add:

```
<head>
  <style>
     .red{
        background-color:red;}
  <style>
</head>
```

You might wanna look at CSS styles: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```css
.bordered {
  padding: 10;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.blue-pair > div {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.red-pair > div {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="bordered blue-pair">
  <div>15</div>
  <div>15</div>
</div>
<div class="bordered red-pair">
  <div>16</div>
  <div>16</div>
</div>
<div class="bordered blue-pair">
  <div>17</div>
  <div>17</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector

```css
div {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
}

div:nth-child(2n+1) {
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-right: none;
}

div:nth-child(2n) {
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
<div>E</div>
<div>F</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible in pure CSS but it can be accomplished using pre-processors like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/functions/#math-functions) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html)

The arithmetic progression to select consecutive elements is floor(nth-child(n+1/2)).

CSS selector nth-child() doesn't allow fractions in the arguments. The browser auto corrects :nth-child(n+1/2) to nth-child(n+1). 
Also, there is no floor function in CSS.